# How to identify unused methods in a framework included in a Swift project?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, linker, frameworks

I am analyzing a swift application that includes several frameworks containing object .o files compiled from Objective-C source files, and the respective headers.

Very few of the methods in the framework libraries are being called so I want to identify what is unused.  Is there a tool or linker setting that will do this?

I've found this but it doesn't work for frameworks:
https://github.com/PaulTaykalo/swift-scripts

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to identify that on a project compile level or in final `Mach-O` executable?

Comment: Do you have the source code of the project ? or you must work on .o files?
If you have the source code of the project, I recommend to you AppCode.
With Appcode You can find the usage of methods and etc.

Comment: @Kamil.S I have the sources to the project but not to the framework.  The framework was compiled from objective-c and includes the .h files

Comment: @RezaDehnavi as above I have he sources to the project but not to the framework.  The framework has the .h files and I want to automatically identify what is being called and what isn't.  I could do it manually or write a small program myself but was hoping there might be a tool that does this.